# How can I sort the results of a REST API response by the title of a connected custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, rest-api, order

I'm using the `rest_photo_query` filter to manipulate the arguments of `WP_Query` through the use of my own `GET` parameters. It's working perfectly and fast, with one exception.

I can adjust the `orderby` parameter using `rest_sht_photo_collection_params`, and it's easy to sort the results by `meta_value`.

The **photo** Custom Post Type entries are connected to a second Custom Post Type **species** by means of the `species_id`.

I need to be able to sort the **photo** posts by **species** title.

Does anyone have a good idea how to achieve this? As I'm modifying the `WP_Query` in a standard endpoint, my preference would be to modify the `WP_Query` arguments somehow.

I've tried building my own query in a custom endpoint and then modifying the resultant array by looping through it, but this makes the request about 100x slower.

Here's a partial example of a simpler field, where the custom orderby `my_custom_meta_field` is added as a `meta_value` comparison:

```
switch ($args['orderby']) {
    case 'my_custom_meta_field':
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'my_custom_meta_field';
        break;
```

Comment: Is it not possible in js? The database won't know that the meta value is a post id, just that it's a number value. Making it then look up that post and do sorting would make it an extreme performance hit. You may find that it takes multiple seconds ( double digits ) to run in production and can only be ran once or twice in parallel without database issues. This isn't something `WP_Query` can do, and adding levels of indirectness is not something you want to do

Comment: JS based sorting should be more scalable and faster for all parts, and could be thousands of times faster

Comment: I see what you mean, but the data set needs to be pre-sorted and pre-filtered (there is a `meta_query` in there too). Otherwise the pagination doesn't work. We're talking about nearly 10,000 posts, so I can't send them all to the frontend and let the browser handle the filtering and sorting.

Comment: Then you're going to have to store the title on the post in the meta. What's the context behind this? It's an unusual request. Would it not make sense to fetch a list of `species` then fetch posts for each species in order and using the species totals count to figure out pagination? The posts first approach is going to be extremely expensive. You're going to want to invest in a lot of caching at multiple levels to make it work at any kind of scale ( think more than a handful of concurrent users/requests )

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did with the custom endpoint. However, the REST response sometimes took nearly 30 seconds to deliver 25 results, which is obviously unacceptable. The regular endpoint comes back in 250ms, even with filtered and sorted data, and everything is done except for this one sort option. I may have to solve it by pre-storing a value against the post; as you said, potentially with a meta entry.

Comment: That's to be expected, what you're doing is very ***very*** expensive to do server side, you've essentially chosen to do it the most expensive way possible. You should not do it in PHP, nothing prevents this being done in javascript and still having pagination, and it being faster on both the browser and server. Your data is just not structured for this kind of query to work, but a JS based solution would be superior and avoid the other problem of updating thousands of posts when a species changes name

Comment: The context is a paginated list of photos, which can be sorted by around a dozen different criteria, filtered by three different options - species name, free text search, and post year - and limited by a posts per page option. If any of these criteria change, I need to get fresh data from the server instantly.

Each of the 10,000 photo posts can be assigned to one of 3,400 species. The list shows the photo, twelve pieces of meta data, and the species name, which is linked to the single view of the species post.

I'm confused as to how filtering/sorting 10,000 posts in the browser can work.

Comment: You don't, you're always going to have to ask the server for data, but how you ask for it can make a massive difference. For example if we have `elephant`, `monkey`, and `zebra`, and we know that there are 20 photos in `elephant`, 10 in `monkey`, and 10 in `zebra`, then that's 20 + 10 + 10 = 40 photos. 10 photos per page, that's 4 pages. We now know enough to figure out which animals are on which pages, and which order we need to request them in. You can figure that out without requesting a single photo from the server, so request all the elephant photos first, then the monkeys, etc

Comment: But also consider that filtering 10k posts is fundamentally expensive, especially via post meta. Listing them all especially is not scalable. There are ways to make it faster, but not fast. The way the data is structured plays a huge part in this, as well as the kind of queries you write. If you want to do this fast, with sub-second query times, and sorted, store the title as a string, put the whole data set in elastic search, and tell ES to sort it

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `WP_Query` can sort by post meta value, but it can't then use that value as a post ID, look up that post, then sort by a value on that other post.

If you had a small number of posts, it could be done by manually sorting the results with PHP.

Fundamentally, the data is not stored in a way that makes this feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a custom post meta value to each photo, containing the species name, then ensuring that the meta is up-to-date by using save_post hooks on the photo and species. The query now works as required and returns the data I need in around 100ms. This means that I can continue to use this solution without having to use JavaScript.